# Hide <h1> page title but keep meta title in <head> of page

Tags: orchardcms

I have a number of pages within my site that I do not want the `<h1>` page title to be displayed on (e.g. home page or pages that use a slide as a page title).

I can hide the title shape easily using placement: `<Place Parts_Title="-"/>`, but the knock-on effect of this is that it prevents the meta title being added to the `head` section of the page.

Can anyone tell me how to hide the title displayed on the page but retain the meta title, without completely removing the `<h1>` from the `Parts.Title` shape?

I have tried targeting the `h1` in CSS, but not all content items have selectors that I can narrow it down to.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Override the TitlePart's shape template, either using the [shape tracing tool](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools) or by adding a shape template file (`Title.cshtml` or `Title.Parts.cshtml`) to your themes `Views` folder.
The default template is:

```cs
 @{
   Layout.Title = Model.Title;
 }

 <h1> @Model.Title </h1>
```

So your new template can have the same code, except for the line with the `h1` tag :)

If you want to render different title shape templates for different content types, use [Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) ie. `Title.Parts-MyContentType.cshtml` is a title shape template only for `MyContentType` content type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't really answer the question. If I remove the <h1> it will hide it on ALL pages. I need to display it on certain pages / content types and hide it on others.

Comment: Alternates to the rescue!

Comment: Ha ha, yeah but I'd need like 5 variations of Parts.Title, only showing / hiding the <h1> tag!! Seems wrong?

Comment: If that's your case, then perhaps you need some code within the template. `if (someCondition)  { <h1> @Model.Title </h1> }`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking - add a flag to the relevant content types (probably as a content part), then check it in the template. I'll write something up when I have a working version - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your should change Title Part Shape (Like @Szymon Seliga suggests)

But for targeting only specific content you could use placement.info something like that:

```
<Match Path="~/">
  <Place Parts_Title="Header:1;Shape=Parts_Title_OnlyMeta"/>
</Match>
<Match ContentType="NameOfContentType">
  <Place Parts_Title="Header:1;Shape=Parts_Title_OnlyMeta"/>
</Match>
```

Also you need to create alternate like that `~/Views/Parts/Title.OnlyMeta.cshtml`